# find nearest point to a point in another table

Tags: postgis-2.0

This similar, but not quite the same as [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136403/postgis-nearest-point-with-st-distance).

I need to pick, regardless of distance, the closest 'n' points to a given point in another table, using postGIS.

Imagine a table with city names, state names, and a centroid for the city itself, and another table with point information on various weather radar sites. Both tables re postGIS enabled.

PostGIS-2 has me confused; it's been awhile since I had to do something line this.