# Pois_close POINT with PostGIS and Rails

Tags: postgis

I try to use PostGIS in Rails and write my first request. I would like have :

- The nearest points of another point (but without this point)
- The name and the distance between them both

In my model I have write this scope :

```
 scope :close_to, -> (latitude, longitude, distance_in_m = 1) {
  where(%{
  ST_Distance(lonlat, 'POINT(%f %f)') < %d
 } % [longitude, latitude, distance_in_m * 1000])
}
```

How can I get the distance ?

Answer (score 0):

Search for the Nearest Neighbor in postgis is a well know problem solved multiple times in stack overflow and the "internet", like:

- [PostGIS nearest point with ST_Distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136403/postgis-nearest-point-with-st-distance?rq=1)
- [PostGIS nearest point with LATERAL JOIN in PostgreSQL 9.3+](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155373/postgis-nearest-point-with-lateral-join-in-postgresql-9-3?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How Do I Find The N Nearest Things To This Point In PostGis](https://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/)

In it's more basic form the query can be written like this:

```
SELECT name, gid, ST_Distance(geom, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-90,40),4326))
FROM geonames
ORDER BY geom <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-90,40),4326)
LIMIT 1;
```

but it can be improved depending on your use case.