# Using st_distance to calculate shortest distance between a table with point geometry to a table with multipolygon geometry

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying and failing to do a calculation of the shortest distance for each point in a point geometry table (15000 records) to the nearest polygon edge in another table (170000 records). The end result I want is a distance for each point record to the nearest polygon record. My tables looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "brondby_adresserV2"(
  kvhx character varying,
  coordx integer,
  coordy integer,
  pk serial NOT NULL,
  the_geom geometry(Point,25832),
  dist_coast double precision,
  dist_lake double precision,
  CONSTRAINT "brondby_adresserV2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (pk)
)
```

and this:

```
CREATE TABLE soe
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  fot_id double precision,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,25832),
  CONSTRAINT soe_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
```

I've tried using John Barca's answer from this post: [PostGIS nearest point with ST_Distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136403/postgis-nearest-point-with-st-distance) where he uses the st_dwithin so that the query uses the geometry index.

The result I get from my query pussles me and something is definately wrong. When visualising the result in qgis, it looks like the calculation is not done to all the polygons.[image: problem visualised] 
This is the code that I've used:

```
update "brondby_adresserV2" set dist_lake = t.foo
from
(
select distinct on ("brondby_adresserV2".kvhx) "brondby_adresserV2".kvhx,
"soe".fot_id, st_distance("brondby_adresserV2".the_geom, "soe".geom) as foo
from "brondby_adresserV2", "soe"
where ST_DWithin("brondby_adresserV2".the_geom, "soe".geom, 5000)
order by "brondby_adresserV2".kvhx, "soe".fot_id,
st_distance("brondby_adresserV2".the_geom, "soe".geom)
) t
where "brondby_adresserV2".kvhx = t.kvhx
```

Can anyone guide me as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you should include the "soe".fot_id in your Order By statement. That will always give you the shortest distance to the first "SOE" record

Comment: or `"brondby_adresserV2".kvhx`

Comment: Also possible @MichaelStoner. But in this case I think I wan't the shortest distance from each address (brondby_adresserV2) to any lake (soe)

Comment: removing     "soe".fot_id doesn't change anything, and the "select distinct on"  function needs "brondby_adresserV2".kvhx as the first input in the order by clause

Comment: Did you remove the "soe".fot_id from the Order By part of your statement or from the Select part?

Comment: But It would make sense that it was sorted by the shortest distance...

Comment: I must be sorted by the shortest distance, but only per address, not per address and lake

Comment: I removed it from the order by part

Comment: you're right, but as I wanted the shortest distance per point I needed to use the select distinct on function, which requires the targeted column to be the first in the order by column. It looked as if it worked in the John Barca example that I linked to, but maybe I need a completely different strategy...

Comment: If you have access to MapInfo Pro, you can use the Distance Calcculator tool

Comment: Did you try running the query only, iwthout the Update part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your query above you will always calculate the shortest distance to the "first" lake within a 5 kilometer distance of your addresses.

"First" is here been determined by the values of the fot_id column.

I would use a statement like this where the Order By statement doesn't use soe.fot_id:

```
update "brondby_adresserV2" set dist_lake = t.foo
from
(
select distinct on ("brondby_adresserV2".kvhx) "brondby_adresserV2".kvhx,
"soe".fot_id, st_distance("brondby_adresserV2".the_geom, "soe".geom) as foo
from "brondby_adresserV2", "soe"
where ST_DWithin("brondby_adresserV2".the_geom, "soe".geom, 5000)
order by "brondby_adresserV2".kvhx, st_distance("brondby_adresserV2".the_geom, "soe".geom)
) t
where "brondby_adresserV2".kvhx = t.kvhx
```

If that doesn't work how about using an aggregation instead?
I guess now is the time for me to admit that I don't have PostGIS installed :-)

```
update "brondby_adresserV2" set dist_lake = t.foo
from
(
select "brondby_adresserV2".kvhx, Min(st_distance("brondby_adresserV2".the_geom, "soe".geom)) as foo
from "brondby_adresserV2", "soe"
where ST_DWithin("brondby_adresserV2".the_geom, "soe".geom, 5000)
Group by "brondby_adresserV2".kvhx
) t
where "brondby_adresserV2".kvhx = t.kvhx
```

Comment: I think that this actually did the trick! I'll test some more and edit my answer if I find any problems. Thank you so much.

Comment: Which of the solutions did the trick, @JonasPedersen?

Comment: The GROUP BY statement (second). Using SELECT DISTINCT ON without the soe.fot_id doesn't make a difference