# Nearest Neighbour function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, table, nearest-neighbor, function

I'm trying to create a function which calculates the nearest neighbors under a certain length in a table s_1 an stores them in an output table.

This is what I've got so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NearestN()   
RETURNS TABLE (     
a integer,
b integer,
ST_Distance integer
)
AS
$$

SELECT ST_Distance(a.the_geom , b.the_geom ) from s_1 a, s_1 b 
 WHERE a.id < b.id  
  AND ST_DWithin(a.the_geom,b.the_geom, 50.0)                   
   ORDER BY ST_Distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom) ASC LIMIT 25;       
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Needless to say to function is not working at all (I'm very new to sql) and I think my calculation does not only get me the nearest neighbor but all distances under a certain length.

And is it possible to make the length an argument of the function so I can vary just by calling the function?

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136403/postgis-nearest-point-with-st-distance/136416#136416 for some ideas. Also, can you please edit your post so the code block is clearly outlined, it makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Indexed Nearest Neighbour Search](http://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/) like

```
SELECT ST_Distance(a.the_geom , b.the_geom ) from s_1 a, s_1 b 
 WHERE a.id < b.id  
  AND ST_DWithin(a.the_geom,b.the_geom, 50.0)                   
   ORDER BY a.the_geom <-> b.the_geom LIMIT 25;
```

Note: I cannot see why you would need the `WHERE a.id < b.id`, you will have to try which version gives you the best result.

Another resource which helped me to understand the Indexed Nearest Neighbour Search was [this blog post](http://geeohspatial.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/k-nearest-neighbor-search-in-postgis.html).