# KNN with "Big Data"

Tags: postgis, nearest-neighbor, knn

I have a point dataset of over 30mill records and I am trying to select the closest 5 lines to each point. Reading this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136403/postgis-nearest-points-with-st-distance-knn) there seems to be two methodologies

1. Using <-> however as I want to select the 5 closest I have used the following

```
select a.id, a.code, array_agg(b.id) AS line_ids
from points p
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT p.id, l.id
    FROM lines l
    ORDER BY a.geom <-> c.geom LIMIT 5
) AS b
where p.id = b.id
```

This ran for a few hours and then failed on a memory allocation (was above 24Gb of RAM)

2. Use ST_DWithin to limit to 500m

```
select p.id, p.code, array_agg(b.id) AS line_ids
from points p
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT p.id, b.id
    FROM lines l
    WHERE ST_DWithin(p.geom, l.geom, 500)
      ORDER BY p.geom <-> l.geom LIMIT 5
) AS b
where p.id = b.id
```

All columns have an index and a spatial index. IS there any better methods or things I am missing to successfully run this query?

Using PostgreSQL 12, PostGIS 3, Windows 64Bit, 32Gb of RAM

Explain for first method

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..433780457.02 rows=5 width=24)
  ->  Seq Scan on points p  (cost=0.00..1643568.42 rows=30634442 width=48)
  ->  Subquery Scan on b  (cost=0.41..14.10 rows=1 width=16)
        Filter: (p.id = b.id)
        ->  Limit  (cost=0.41..14.03 rows=5 width=24)
              ->  Index Scan using geometry_geom_idx on open_usrn c  (cost=0.41..3997260.47 rows=1467289 width=24)
                    Order By: (geometry <-> a.geom)
```

Explain for second method

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=5244082420.90..5244082421.01 rows=5 width=48)
  Group Key: p.id, b.id
  ->  Sort  (cost=5244082420.90..5244082420.91 rows=5 width=24)
        Sort Key: p.id, p.code
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.66..5244082420.84 rows=5 width=24)
              ->  Seq Scan on points a  (cost=0.00..1797087.20 rows=33052020 width=48)
              ->  Subquery Scan on b  (cost=0.66..158.60 rows=1 width=16)
                    Filter: (p.id = b.id)
                    ->  Limit  (cost=0.66..158.53 rows=5 width=24)
                          ->  Index Scan using geometry_geom_idx on open_usrn c  (cost=0.66..4642.10 rows=147 width=24)
                                Index Cond: (geometry && st_expand(a.geom, '500'::double precision))
                                Order By: (geometry <-> a.geom)
                                Filter: st_dwithin(a.geom, geometry, '500'::double precision)
```

Comment: try clustering the index - `CLUSTER table USING index_name`

Comment: `ST_DWithin` adds an unnecessary function call to the execution, while `<->` has a more specialized index lookup already included; use option 1. Don't pull the `points.id` from the `LATERAL` query. However, in either way, clustered or not, you are doing +30M proximity checks on at least 5 LineStrings each. Consider creating a new table rather then `SELECT` (why at all?) or `UPDATE` (for reasons you mentioned in comments), or sub-selecting points in AOIs only (e.g. within bbox: `&&`).

Comment: @geozelot it is part of a CREATE TABLE i just left that bit out to simplify my question. I just wanted to confirm that I am not missing anything obvious. Will see if I can break it down further, thanks