# Pgrouting: problem with pgr_withpointsDD

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, network

I'd like to calculate a propagation from sources using my road graph. In extenso, I'd like to answer the following question: where are the limits of my isochrones for every sources I got. My sources (point) are not on the graph but outside.

No problem to create my graph.

Here's how I create a table with the sources and elements attaching them to my graph:

```
create table exo.psource as 
(with poi as (
    select p.gid as gid_pt, 
        p."q (m3/h)" as debit, 
        p.volume as volume, 
        p.geom  
    from exo.epi  p
    )
SELECT
    poi.gid_pt::int4,
    poi.volume::int8, 
    poi.debit::int4,
    closest_tr.gid::int4,
    closest_tr.dist::double precision,
    st_linelocatepoint(closest_tr.geom, poi.geom)::double precision as fraction
FROM poi
LEFT JOIN LATERAL 
    (SELECT
        t.gid, 
        ST_Distance(t.geom, poi.geom) as dist,
        t.geom
    FROM exo.troncon t 
    ORDER BY poi.geom <-> t.geom
    LIMIT 1
    ) AS closest_tr
ON TRUE
)
```

After that I run the following query to get the vertices at 200m or less from my sources:

```
select 
    pgr.*, 
t   vp.the_geom 
from
pgr_withPointsDD(
    'select gid AS id, nsource::int4 AS source, ncible::int4 AS target, st_length(geom)::float8 AS cost, st_length(geom)::float8 as reverse_cost 
    from exo.troncon'::text, 'select gid_pt as pid, gid as edge_id, fraction from exo.source'::text, 
    (
        select
            array_agg(exo.source.gid_pt order by gid_pt asc) from exo.source
    ) , -- un array de tous les id de mes sources
    200
,
    details := true
    ) pgr
left join exo.troncon_vertices_pgr tvp on tvp.id = pgr.node
```

Everything seems correct in my (favorite) GIS:
[image: result]

Except: for some sources, the closest edge hasn't been browsed (see source 2 to vertex 142 by example)

What did I miss?

No vertex is exactly at 200m from a source, how do I calculate the remaining part of edges to get 200m exactly?
My sources are distants of the edge, how do I integrate this distance into the calculation?

I'm quite sure the solution to this probleme may benefit a lot of people.

I orignally post this problem on a french forum.

[Here are the datas](http://pmuckensturm.fr/gis/data.gpkg)

I've read those articles and used them partially or fully to solve (not totally) my problem:

[présentation foss4g](https://osgeo-fr.github.io/presentations_foss4gfr/2016/J1/20160511_FOSS4G_FR_Poppy.pdf)

[une question sur gis stackeexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136403/postgis-nearest-points-with-st-distance-knn)

[un post de bostongis](https://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/categories/7-nearest-neighbor)

[article sur geoafrica](https://geoafrica.fr/laccessibilite-multimodale-en-isochrones/)

Answer (score 1):

*There are too many questions in this post, but let me address the most prominent issue:*

You are not getting the correct results (*at all!*) because you are using the **wrong vertice identifiers**; all functions in the `withPoints` family require the `points` to have **negative `pid`s**.

As it stands, your query will **not use any `point` from your `exo.sources` table**, but those from `exo.troncon_vertices_pgr` with corresponding ids; look closely at your results above!

Rather, force the `exo.sources.gid_pt` values to be negative, e.g. here

```
(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(-gid_pt ORDER BY gid_pt ASC) FROM exo.source)
```

and also, since you specified `details := true`, include the `points` in the result set, e.g. like so

```
[...] AS pgr
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id, geom FROM exo.troncon_vertices_pgr
  UNION ALL
  SELECT -gid_pt AS id, geom FROM exo.source
) AS tvp
  ON tvp.id = pgr.node
;
```

---

*And also the easiest of your secondary issues:*

It's easy to include the actual distance from your `exo.source.geom` to their nearest `exo.troncon.geom` into the calculations; just filter the `pgr.agg_cost` for values greater than `200 - exo.source.dist`, e.g. like so

```
[...]
  ON  tvp.id = pgr.node
WHERE pgr.agg_cost < (SELECT 200-dist FROM exo.source WHERE -gid_pt = pgr.start_vid)
;
```

There are likely better ways to do this, but it works just fine.

---

*About the remaining issue:*

Getting the partial edges for the remaining distance after the last reachable node is more involved and likely due for a separate question (if you can't find a similar one on the board), right after you sorted this one out.

Comment: @Brindavoine did you find a solution for the remaining issue?